# preventing Vue from aggresively reusing dom-elements

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Condider the following snippet:

```
        <template v-if="tryIsMobile" >
          <div class='device device-mobile-portrait' :class="deviceClass">
            <div class="device-scroller-container">
              <div class='device-scroller'>
                <img id='tryit-img-mobile' :src="srcUrlMobile" v-on:load="onImgLoad" v-on:error="onImgError"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>

        <template v-else>
          <div class='device device-tablet-landscape' :class="deviceClass" >
            <div class="device-scroller-container">
              <div class='device-scroller'>
                <img  id='tryit-img-tablet' :src="srcUrlTablet" v-on:load="onImgLoad" v-on:error="onImgError"/>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </template>
```

This code conditionally renders one of the two images. Some user action results in the actual shown image to be toggled.

What I'm seeing is the following: When toggling from say, `tryit-img-mobile` to `tryit-img-tablet`, the image loaded as part of `tryit-img-mobile` will get displayed with different dimensions instantly. However, during the time the image loads it's new source `:src="srcUrlTablet"`, the image with src `:src="srcUrlMobile"` still displays.

This is probably due to Vue using the same img-tag for both the templates. How can I prevent Vue from doing this, and instead use seperate img-tags?

Comment: Add a `key` attribute on your `device` elements, with some unique value, like `key="desktop"` and `key="mobile"`. That will tell Vue not to reuse the elements.

Comment: @JosephSilber: woeha, that appears to have solved it! If you'd jot that down as an aswer I'm happy to accept.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In cases such as this, Vue uses a special `key` attribute that tells it not to reuse the same element. Give each element this attribute with a unique value, and Vue will no longer reuse the same element:

```html
<div v-if="tryIsMobile"
     class="device device-mobile-portrait"
     :class="deviceClass"
     key="mobile"
>
    ...
</div>
<div v-else
     class="device device-tablet-landscape"
     :class="deviceClass"
     key="tablet"
>
    ...
</div>
```